# Executing a command in running docker swarm service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, elastic

I am trying to run a Django project in docker swarm mode. The problem is I want to index the Elastic search container which needs to be run only after postgres completes the SQL dumping process (only in the first run). How can I do this? Any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a `cronjob` container that does the SQL dump and elastic index using `docker exec` commands toward the corresponding containers.

Comment: but cron will not know if the DB import has been completed or not. if the import task is not complete then elastic search indexing will produce an error

Comment: @Bikram wait for your dump task to exit and check its return code before running the ES indexing in one cron